# Change content of multiple elements using Javascript without for loop

Tags: javascript, html, class

I am trying to change the content of multiple elements with the same id, using:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('price_01').innerHTML = price_01;
document.getElementById('dimension_01').innerHTML = dimension_01;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var price_01 = '$8000';
    var dimension_01 = '10m';
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('price_01').innerHTML = price_01;
    document.getElementById('dimension_01').innerHTML = dimension_01;
 }
  </script>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>W3.CSS Modal</h2>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td id='price_01'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dimension:</td>
            <td id='dimension_01'></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <div class="w3-container">
          <table class="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Price:</td>
                  <td id='price_01'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Dimension:</td>
                  <td id='dimension_01'></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            
</body>
</html>
```

However, it seems that the code doesn't work because you can only have one unique id for each element. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem without for loops and class? I have a lot of these elements to populate and I don't really want to write a for loops for each of them.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same id in one document is **invalid HTML**.  Fix that first.

Comment: So I have to use class for that?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but using a class is probably the clearest option.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with just function, similarly to the code with id:

document.getElementById('price_01').innerHTML = price_01;

Comment: It you must… `document.querySelectorAll()` will return all the identical ids. (i.e `document.querySelectorAll("#price_01")`)

Comment: Do you mean: 

document.querySelectorAll('price_01').innerHTML = price_01;

I tried it and it didn't work: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTJLRGLQC0F3

Comment: no…you'll need to `forEach` them…so still a loop.

Comment: I just really want to avoid for loops as I have price_01, price_02, ... price_n. Is there really no way to do it with just function?

Comment: What's wrong with a nested for loop? For each container, loop through price_01, price_02, etc.

Comment: Using jQuery selector it's possible. For example try this one in this page's console.
    $('.grid--cell').text('Voilaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..a.a.a.a..a.aaaa.a.aaaaaaaaaa..a.a.a.a..')